# DataType mvc empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Model with properties like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[MaxLength(512)]
public string Description
{
    get
    {
        this.OnReadingDescription(ref _description);
        return _description;
    }
    set
    {
        this.OnDescriptionChanging(ref value);
        this._description = value;
        this.OnDescriptionChanged();
    }
}
```

and a View like this:

```
@using AspMvcBase.Bootstrap
@model NpoDb.Presentation.Web.Models.Media
@Html.EditForm();
```

EditForm is a custom HtmlHelper extension which renders every property in the ViewModel.
This part works realy fine but I want do render some of the properties different so I added the [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)] Attribute.

I want to test now in my HtmlHelper if there is an Attribute for a MultilineText.

```
modelMetadata.DataTypeName.Equals(DataType.EmailAddress.ToString())
```

But the problem is that DataTypeName is null. Even if I look at it in the View it's null.

This is one of the better resources I found about this.[Brad Wilson MVC2 Template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html)

But I can't figure out why it doesn't work in my case.

So the basic question is: How can I access Attributes in a HtmlHelper?

I would really appreciate some help. :)

Comment: How do you get the *modelMetadata*?

Comment: In the EditForm extension I have a loop like:
foreach (var prop in helper.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    "Code which renders the view where I need the Attributes"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the attribute for a property of your model, you can do this:

```
public static string EditForm(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
   var model = helper.ViewData.Model;
   var dataType = model
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty("Description")
        .GetCustomAttribute<DataTypeAttribute>()
        .DataType;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :) The solution for my problem is that I run through the Properties of the ModelMetadata because I need some infos from there. In the loop I use then your sugestion PropertyInfo propertyInfo = helper.ViewData.Model.GetType().GetProperty(modelMetadata.PropertyName).GetCustomAttribute<DataTypeAttribute>();
to get the Attributes.

Comment: The strange thing is that I have an expample project of my teacher and by him the DataTypeName contains the attribute info, but as we both couldn't figure out why it doesn't work by my soloution. This seems to be the way to work around this problem :)